# What happens in the "Help and Improvement" queue if I vote for VLQ while I have a flag ban?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, help-improvement

I am a relative active reviewer in the "Help and Improvement" queue. In the cases of questions I consider unfixable LQ, I click the "question is a very low quality" link. As I know, it puts the question into the VLQ queue, and it jumps me to the next "Help and Improvement" review item.

But, the VLQ queue can relative easily get a "disputed" result; compared to other review queues, far fewer supporting vote is enough to a "disputed" result - and the number of the "disputed" flags resulted now in a temporary flag ban.

Note, I have absolutely no problem with this flag ban - I interpret this as an urge to be more lenient with the VLQ votes, at least in the "Help and Improvement" queue. I wish to follow this.

But, in the cases of a *really* LQ question, I wish to still click the "question is a very low quality" link. The problem is that I don't know if it is harmful or not.

Now my question is, what will happen in this case?

What I see: these clicks doesn't appear as VLQ flags in my flag history. Thus, the result is analogous to if I had clicked the "Skip".

But I won't click skip - I think, having many skipped reviews would annoy my review history in the "review reviews" function of the mods and 10k+ users. This is not my intent.

So, how these clicks appear in my review history?

What should I do?

- I could suspend my "Help and Improvement" reviews until the expiration of the flag ban.
- I could try to improve even the questions what doesn't seem to have any chance (or if I don't have any idea, how could they be improved in any sense).
- I could still click "Question is a very low quality", and hoping that I don't harm anything with it.

What to do? Any idea?

Comment: Disputed flags are neutral - too many of them doesn't get you banned from flagging.

Comment: Skipped reviews are also entirely neutral and usually the appropriate action in H&I.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 10k+ users and mods have a "review reviews" privilege, which contains my review history, I think this view can be harassed in this case. None of us being 10k+, we don't know how harmful is this behavior. (Normally, if I think a question is salvageable, I try to fix anything in it what I can.)

Comment: @dorukayhan Ok, thanks! But, I didn't flag anything on the main since long for mod intervention, despite that I am currently flag-banned (but, only for 7 days - this I also don't understand, last time they were much longer).

Comment: Don't flag content as VLQ that isn't actually VLQ. You shouldn't be flagging stuff with the intention of sending it to Triage or the Low Quality Posts review queues. You should be flagging stuff with the intention of having a moderator review your flag. If the flag is handled through review, that's a bonus.

Comment: @TinyGiant Yes, they are VLQ. I vote mainly as the link says in your profile.